# React Native Error : Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: react-native

I am experiencing an issue (Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED) with React Native only on the Android side when attempting to start up the app.
The iOS side works as expected. Here is the version of everything that is being used :

OpenJDK version 11.0.20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.66.15-CA(build 11.0.20+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.66+15-CA(build 11.0.20+8-LTS, mixed mode

Node: v16.20.1
Yarn: 1.22.19

Gradle: zulu 11: Azul Zulu version 11.0.21
Android SDK Platform API Level 34
Google APIs Arm  64 v8a System Image
Android Sdk Platform 33
Source for Android 33
Android SDK Build Tools 34.0.0
Android SDK Build Tools 33.0.0
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.2

This setup works for another person but not for me. Please help. Thank You

We have tried to clean the Gradle and most of the other advices online before asking. None of the advices online solved the issue.